# R: update the values in df1 based on data in df2

Tags: r

Hi I have two data frames (df1 and df2) with two shared variables (ID and Yr). I want to update the values in a third variable (value) in df1 with the new data in the respective value in df2. But below code does not update the value in df1, it seems the values are not passed to the corresponding cels in df1.

```
df1 = data.frame(ID = c("a","b","c","d","e") ,
                 Yr = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004), 
                 value= c(100,100,100,100, 100))
df2 = data.frame(ID = c("a","b","c") ,
                 Yr = c(2000,2001,2002), 
                 valuenew= c(200,150,120))


for (i in 1:nrow(df2)){
  id <- df2[i,'ID']
  year <- df2[i, 'Yr']
  valuenew<- df2[i, 'valuenew']
  df1[which (df1$ID == id & df1$Yr == year), 'value'] <- valuenew
}
```

the desired result

```
   ID  Yr   value
    a  2000   200
    b  2001   150
    c  2002   120
    d  2003   100
    e  2004   100
```

The real data I use with which none of these solutions works

```
df1    
head(df1, 5)
                           CoreID   Yr   FluxTot
1 Asmund2000_Greenland coast_4001 1987 0.3239693
2 Asmund2000_Greenland coast_4001 1986 0.2864100
3 Asmund2000_Greenland coast_4001 1985 0.2488508
4 Asmund2000_Greenland coast_4001 1984 0.2964794
5 Asmund2000_Greenland coast_4001 1983 0.3441080

df2
head(df2, 5)
                      CoreID   Yr GamfitHgdep
1       Beal2015_Mount Logan 2000  0.01105077
2 Eyrikh2017_Belukha glacier 2000  0.02632597
3       Zheng2014_Mt. Oxford 2000  0.01377599
4          Zheng2014_Agassiz 2000  0.01940151
5     Zheng2014_NEEM-2010-S3 2000 -0.01483026

#merged database
m<-merge(df1, df2)
head(m,5)

              CoreID   Yr     FluxTot  GamfitHgdep
1 Beal2014_Yanacocha 2000 0.003365556  0.024941373
2 Beal2014_Yanacocha 2001 0.003423333  0.027831253
3 Beal2014_Yanacocha 2002 0.003481111 -0.002908330
4 Beal2014_Yanacocha 2003 0.003538889 -0.004591100
5 Beal2014_Yanacocha 2004 0.003596667  0.005189858
```

[image]
[image]
Below is the exact code I used to do the trick but failed. No difference if the value assigning part is replaced with any other solutions. No warning, no error raised.

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

metal = 'Hg' 
df = read_excel('All core data.xlsx','Sheet1')
df = data.frame(df)
df1 <- df[which (df$Metal==metal),] 
rownames(df1) = seq(length=nrow(df1))
head(df1, 5)

dfgam = read_excel('GAM prediction.xlsx','Sheet1')
df2 <- data.frame(dfgam)
head(df2, 5)

for (i in 1:nrow(df2)){
  coreid <- df2[i,'CoreID']
  year <- df2[i, 'Yr']
  predicted<- df2[i, 'GamfitHgdep']
  df1[which (df1$CoreID == coreid & df1$Yr == year), 'FluxTot'] <- predicted
}
```

after running the code, the values in df1 have not changed, for instance
[image]

the value should be 0.024941373 as shown in `head(m,5)`

Answer (score 4):

Since `dplyr` version 1.0.0, you can use `rows_update` for this:

```r
dplyr::rows_update(
    df1, 
    rename(df2, value=valuenew), 
    by = c("ID", "Yr")
)
#   ID   Yr value
# 1  a 2000   200
# 2  b 2001   150
# 3  c 2002   120
# 4  d 2003   100
# 5  e 2004   100
```

Comment: Great option using `rows_update`!

Comment: Good solution, but keep in mind that it is an Experimental function and subject to potential change!

Comment: @Adam yes after getting used to `dcast` / `melt`, `gather` / `spread`, `pivot_longer` / `pivot_wider`, I am used to `tidyverse` functions changing... but if I didn't ever use them my life would be a lot harder!

Comment: @SamR oh 100% agree. use with caution! just know the state before you use it

Answer (score 1):

Option using `data.table`:

```r
df1 = data.frame(ID = c("a","b","c","d","e") ,
                 Yr = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004), 
                 value= c(100,100,100,100, 100))
df2 = data.frame(ID = c("a","b","c") ,
                 Yr = c(2000,2001,2002), 
                 valuenew= c(200,150,120))

library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, value := i.valuenew, on = .(ID, Yr)]
df1
#>    ID   Yr value
#> 1:  a 2000   200
#> 2:  b 2001   150
#> 3:  c 2002   120
#> 4:  d 2003   100
#> 5:  e 2004   100
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is cool and I imagine quicker than `rows_update()` with large datasets. Do you know any documention on how this syntax works? It's surprisingly hard to google `i.` with `data.table` - you get lots of hits about `i,j` indexing.

Comment: @SamR, But in short, it means that it has to take the values from `valuenew` of dataframe `df2`.

Answer (score 1):

We could use a join for this: For example `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by="ID") %>% 
  mutate(value = ifelse(!is.na(valuenew), valuenew, value)) %>% 
  select(ID, Yr=Yr.x, value)
```

```
 ID   Yr value
1  a 2000   200
2  b 2001   150
3  c 2002   120
4  d 2003   100
5  e 2004   100
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is working and updating `df1` just fine.

However, to add one more solution, you can try the lines below without using a for loop or attaching extra packages:

```r
key <- paste(df1$ID, df1$Yr)
values <- setNames(df2$value, paste(df2$ID, df2$Yr))[key]
df1$value[!is.na(values)] <- values[!is.na(values)]
```

Maybe something worth to mention in general for your problem, make sure you don't have any duplicated ID/Yr combinations in `df2`...

EDIT:

Sorry, I was terrible at helping you! Providing just another working solution is not helpful at all. So here's my attempt to help you further.

First, check that you have the classes/types that you expect for the columns that you compare.

Next - usually I'd recommend placing a `browser()` in your code (e.g. before your assignment/last line in your example:

```r
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)){
  id <- df2[i,'ID']
  year <- df2[i, 'Yr']
  valuenew<- df2[i, 'valuenew']
  browser()
  df1[which (df1$ID == id & df1$Yr == year), 'value'] <- valuenew
}
```

This is especially helpful if you need to debug a function. However in your case you can step through your for loop manually, which is a bit simpler to handle:

Assign the first value to your iterator `i <- 1` and run the code inside your for loop. Is `which(df1$ID == id & df1$Yr == year)` really returning what you expect?

If you can't find any issues, increment `i` by `1` and proceed with debugging...

Comment: I am so confused, like you said the example and all the solutions (including my own) here work just fine, but when I run the code with my own data, none of these solutions works, no error or warning raised, just the new data do not pass to df1.

Comment: Can you add your exact code that your trying to run with, say, the top 5 rows of your two data.frames? You can drop any columns which are not used by your code...

Comment: Maybe one check before pasting your code - are you sure you do have identical column classes and it's not an issue of comparing a character vector in one data.frame with a numeric vector in the other (e.g. for column `Yr`)?

Comment: Hi @Chris, thank you so much for your reply, I have added the information you mentioned to the post, could you please help to check what is wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @Elizabeth, you have a typo in your example code - you check the `df1` matches with a logical or (`|`) instead of and... However, this should still modify `df1`, just not correctly. Are you really sure that you do have matching ID/year pairs in both df1 and df2? What does `merge(df1, df2)` give you as output? If it is empty, you don't have any matching pairs...

Comment: Hi @Chris, I have changed | to & as you pointed out. But still, it is not working, I have tried merge(df1, df2) it works fine and produced a data frame with the same number of rows as that of df2. Any thoughts? again, I appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: Dear @Elizabeth, this is rather strange. I've updated my answer. Step through your for loop and check for each expression/assignment that you evaluate if it produces the value that you expect. If you can't solve the problem like that, I can't help you further, I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `for` loop

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
    y <- which(df1$Yr[i] == df2$Yr)
    if(length(y) > 0) df1$value[i] <- df2$valuenew[y]
}
```

- Output

```
  ID   Yr value
1  a 2000   200
2  b 2001   150
3  c 2002   120
4  d 2003   100
5  e 2004   100
```